# AxWindowsMediaPlayer DVD Player?

Tags: windows-media-player, dvd, axwindowsmediaplayer

Simple question: How do you play a standard DVD in an `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` control?

I've tried using the functions in `AxWindowdsMediaPlayer.dvd`, but none of them seemed to do anything...

Comment: Well... **How about the [`dvd` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562413.aspx)**, which returns an [`IWMPDVD` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563252.aspx)?

Comment: I've looked into that... but none of the functions seemed to do anything.

Comment: Would have been a good thing to mention in your question. Tell us what you've tried and what didn't work. (I sort of assumed you had to have tried that, that's why I didn't post it as an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the `AxWindowdsMediaPlayer.URL` property to the path to the VIDEO_TS.IFO file on the DVD.
Then `AxWindowdsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play()` will play that file.

You will need an instance of `AxWindowdsMediaPlayer` to make these calls on. I don't think they are static.